# Telnet : connect, send command and exit in just one line

Tags: bash, telnet

I try to use telnet in a script (to be use in python program). I want to do the connection, send a command, and exit the connection in juste one line. The command i want to send is to start a program on a remote machine but I d'ont want to wait the end of this program to exit the telnet connection.

I try to do : "echo myCommand | netcat 192.168.1.50 23" but it waits the end of the program.

thanks for your help

Comment: Do you know how to start a command in the background in your shell locally? If you do then the second thing you need to know is about [the `nohup` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html).

Answer (score 6):

Use bash builtin tcp socket feature:

```
echo yourCommand >/dev/tcp/192.168.1.50/23
```

Comment: I find this immensely useful to control my Denon AVR's volume etc. from the PC, thanks a lot!